# Duplicate row based on condition - then change variable name

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like below.

```
ID  Date      Count  
123 31DEC2017 2  
456 31DEC2017 1  
789 31DEC2017 2
```

What I want is if count is 2(count is always 1 or 2) create a new row with adding '.v2' to ID. It should look like below.

```
ID     Date      Count  
123    31DEC2017 2  
123.v2 31DEC2017 2  
456    31DEC2017 1  
789    31DEC2017 2  
789.v2 31DEC2017 2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since SAS is a looping language that reads row-by-row, you can do this very easily in a few lines. Here's what we'll do:

1. When we read any row, we always output it
2. If we encounter count=2, we append `.v2` to `id` and output the row again

```
data want;
    set have;
    
    output;

    if(count=2) then do;
        id = cats(id, '.v2');
        output;
    end;
run;
```

```
id      date        count
123     31DEC2017   2
123.v2  31DEC2017   2
456     31DEC2017   1
789     31DEC2017   2
789.v2  31DEC2017   2
```

If `id` is not a character, you will need to convert it into a character first. Or, simply add a new column that denotes the count is a duplicate. Here are both of those ways:

Converting `id` to a character:

```
data want;
    length id $10.;
    set have(rename=(id = _id));
    
    id = strip(_id);
    output;
    
    if(count=2) then do;
        id = cats(id, '.v2');
        output;
    end;

    drop _id;
run;
```

Creating a new column:

```
data want;
    set have;
    
    output;

    if(count=2) then do;
        version = 'v2';
        output;
    end;
run;
```